# How to get coordinates of an image on mousemove event, should get a unique on any system resolution?

Tags: java, image, jsf, imagemap

can you help in this please?

My question is, how do I get the coordinates of image when I move mouse on it. I am getting this right now. But the problem is, it is giving the different coordinate values on different resolutions..?

Can't I get a unique coordinate values?

Comment: There is no one standard component in JSF which does that. You seem to be either using a 3rd party component library or homegrowing some stuff. Please elaborate in detail how exactly you've approached this so far.

Answer (score 0):

To get an unique coordinates you can convert resolution in pixels (which you're getting right now) to percentage of the screen. For example if you get coordinates 64x48 and the screen resolution is 640x480 it can be converted to 10% x 10% which is resolution independent coordinates.